# Would like to have an Adobe Animate CC banner ad to loop 2x

Tags: jquery-animate, adobe, cc

I'm working on a basic banner ad and would like it to loop 2x then stop. I can't figure it out. Any simple answers?

Answer (score 0):

Write this in the last frame:

```
if (!this.loop) 
    this.loop = 1;

if (this.loop++ == 2) 
    this.stop();
```